# How to read the Location header from a POST API in angularjs?

Tags: post, angularjs, http-headers

My post method is something like this:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage AddUser(User user)
    {
        UserManager userManager = new UserManager();
        try
        {
            userManager.Create(user);

            var savedUser = userManager.FindUserByClientId(user.ClientId);
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, user);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = savedUser.Id }));
            return response;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

In angular, I am trying to read that Location header but so far I'm still not able to.

```
return $http.post('http://localhost:30028/api/values/adduser', user)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            alert(angular.toJson(data));
            alert(angular.toJson(status));
            alert(angular.toJson(headers));
            alert(angular.toJson(config));
         };
```

I am just checking out the contents of each of those and none has the location header. Is there a way in angular to access the location header so that i know the url of my new object?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[According to the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http#Returns), the `headers` object is actually a function that returns the header, like so:

```js
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    alert( headers('Location') );
});
```

If you want a collection of all headers, you can do this:

```js
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log( headers() );
});
```

**Note:** If your server sets a response code of `301` or `302`, you will **not** be able to get the `Location` header, as it will be automatically and transparently followed by the XMLHttpRequest object.

So, make sure you are correctly setting the response code.  I was testing this in PHP (which I don't use as much), and had forgotten that setting a `Location` header automatically set the response code.  To test this, I had to use:

```
header('Location: blah-blah', true, 200);
```

Here's my working code sample, just save it to `location-test.php` on a PHP server and run it:

```php
<?php

if(isset($_GET['q'])) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    header('Location: user/1', true, 200);
    echo json_encode(array('query' => $_GET['q']));
} else {

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <script type='text/javascript' src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.1.5/angular.min.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller("myController", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.loc = "Loading...";
    $http.get('location.php?q=hello')
        .success(function (data, status, header, config) {
            console.log(header());
            $scope.loc = header('Location');
         })
        .error(function(data, status) {
            console.log((data || 'Req Failed') + ': ' + status);
        });
});
  //]]></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
        Location Header: {{loc}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<?php

}
```

Comment: Doesn't this break HTTP? Location isn't supposed to go with 200's.

Comment: @MikaelÖstberg it goes with 202s just fine. http://farazdagi.com/blog/2014/rest-long-running-jobs/

Answer (score 2):

Since `.success()` is deprecated in $http and has been replaced with [`.then()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) the update to this answer is to call `header` directly on the response that is injected into the promise.

```
$http.post('http://localhost:30028/api/values/adduser', user)
    .then(function (response) {
        alert(angular.toJson(response.headers));
        //or
        alert(response.headers('Location'));
 });
```