# AngularJS $resource interceptors

Tags: angularjs, http, rest, resources, interceptor

How do I add interceptors to a `$resource` call?

Let's say I have a resource factory called `Users`, like so;

```
app.factory('Users', ['$resource', 'resourceInterceptor',
  function ($resource, resourceInterceptor) {
    return $resource(
      'users/:user_id',
      {
        user_id: '@id'
      },
      {
        query: {
          method: 'GET', // Not changing the default method, just adding an interceptor
          interceptor: resourceInterceptor // Is there any better way to do this.. like globally?
        },
        save: {
          method: 'POST', // Same here
          interceptor: resourceInterceptor // Again...
        },
        ..., // And so on
      }
    );
  }]);
```

and my `resourceInterceptor` service looks like;

```
app.factory('resourceInterceptor', ['$rootScope',
  function ($rootScope) {
    return {
      request: function () {
        // This function isn't executed at all?
        $rootScope.loading = true;
      },
      response: function () {
        $rootScope.loading = false;
      },
      responseError: function () {
        $rootScope.loading = false;
      }
    };
  }]);
```

First of all, the `request` intercept function is never executed, why not?

Secondly, having to hardcode the interceptor to existing `$resource` methods is very tedious , is there a way to easier assign interceptors to specific `$resource` calls, or maybe even assign an interceptor to all `$resource` calls?

Comment: Hello @Unidan. One year later ... do you have an answer to your question ?

Answer (score 16):

To use an interceptor in a resource you should:

1 - Make an httpInterceptor with you request, response, responseError:

```
app.factory('myInterceptor', function () {
    //Code
    //return { request:...,
});
```

2 - Config this Interceptor in your app:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptor');
}]);
```

Right now as you have config your httpProvider to has an interceptor wherever you inject $http you will use this provider so... you will excute your request, response and responseError funciton.

3 - Using it in a resource.
As $resource use $http and you have config a httpProvider globaly you will call your interceptors' func when you use your resource.

Second question:
You can not set an interceptor to a concrete $http object, they (interceptors) are set globally.

(Even if you set the interceptor before your module definition and then you remove it, you can not know the execution order)

What you can do if you do not want to override the interceptor property in each $resource action (as you write in your question) you can improve your interceptor.

```
app.factory('userLoadingInterceptor', function () {
    //Code
    return {
        request: function(){
            //Check if your are working with a url related with users
            // and if so do things...
        }
});
```

Comment: Yeah but is there a way to specifically identify which requests are called through a `$resource` object, and which is just plain `$http`.

Comment: As $resource use $http and as you are defining an interceptor in the $httpProvider. Your interceptor only do things at $http level. I am going to edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> The interceptor object has two optional methods - response and responseError

I don't know what you want to achieve but generic HTTP interceptors might be an alternative.

Comment: Afaik, the `$resource` service uses `$http`. The docs for `$http` interceptors (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#!) has a `request` field.

Comment: @WillB Do you really think the angular docs are wrong? `$resource` uses `$http`, but the interceptors used by `$resource` have no relation whatsoever to the interceptors of the `$http` service. Another alternative might be a decorator for `$resource`.

Comment: No, of course I don't think the docs are wrong. I just can't find the docs for `$resource` interceptors, so I assumed it was the same as `$http` interceptors. (Found it now on my laptop, was on mobile before). Well that sucks. What I want to achieve is a loading bar that is only shown when using a resource. I'll take a look at decorators.

Answer (score 0):

A generic HTTP Interceptor should do what you want. You can find a sample here: [Handle HTTP 302 response from proxy in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737674/handle-http-302-response-from-proxy-in-angularjs/20864014#20864014).

Comment: Adding an interceptor to the `$http`  service will also trigger when angular loads static assets behind the scenes, which is not desired. Im sure there are ways to detect what kind of request it is, but it feels wrong. I guess I can just make a service that is injected to my controllers and deal with it there.

Comment: You should be able to configure the interceptor to not handle the error based upon the URL.