# How to handle 302 redirect with JavaScriot/AngularJS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, redirect

From my JavaScript application I need to request some url that have two redirects(302) during the invocation.

This url works perfectly in the browser address bar but doesn't work via JavaScript $.get method. I know that there are problems with handling 302 redirect via JavaScript and GET.

Is any other ways in JavaScript to correctly handle this url with redirects ?

**UPDATED**

The following code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: 'https://example.com',
  complete: function(xhr) {
    console.log(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
  }
});
```

and

```
$.get( "https://example.com", function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
  console.log(jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders());
});
```

returns:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible. But do you know the ultimate address and update it?

Comment: I know the final address but I need these redirects because it collects the required data during the invocation.

Comment: What do you see in the Location header? Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737674/handle-http-302-response-from-proxy-in-angularjs

Comment: I have updated my question body with all response headers