# My API Service kept falling into error case - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

## Service

```
app.service('service', function ($http, $q) {

    //Testing code
    var self = this;

    self.login = (user) => {
        let defer = $q.defer();
        let login  = {
            username: user.username,
            password: user.password
        };

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: `http://1.1.1.1/login`,
            data: login
        }).then(
            (response) => {
                defer.resolve(response.data)
            },
            (error) => defer.reject(error)
        );

        return defer.promise;
    };

});
```

---

## Controller

```
angular.module('app').controller('controller',
    ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', 'service','$log' ,'$q',
    function($scope, $rootScope, $location, service, $log, $q) {

        console.log('controller called');

        $scope.changeView = function(view) {
            $location.path(view);
        };

        $scope.user = {username: 'john@nuc.com', password: 'qqq'};
        console.log($scope.user);

        service.login($scope.user)
        .then(
            (response) => {
                console.log('success');
            },
            (error) => console.log('error' + error.data)
        );

    }]);
```

---

## Result

I see these

```
{location: "http://ddddd.com/hom…zg2fQ.D9pDqUBD3bcKnH_bPoGCpd-odxJ48LUZTKOGZZnV0Y0"}
```

I don't know why I am falling into an `error` case section, but I seem to get a proper response back from the server.

**Can someone please shed some lights on this?**

Comment: That picture only shows the request. What is the response? Status outside the range 200...299 return rejected promises.

Comment: @georgeawg response seems working fine with  the data I expected  to get back.

Comment: And what is `response.status`?

Comment: I  can't access `response.status` because my code keep going into the `error` block.

Comment: The `status` property is also attached to the object returned to the rejection handler.

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: no console. error. I shared console screenshot.

Comment: I even try placing the debugger, it still only go into the error section. https://i.imgur.com/ZymSdMF.png

Comment: Handle 302 in error section as in this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737674/handle-http-302-response-from-proxy-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service uses a [deferred anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750207/is-this-a-deferred-antipattern). While that is not the source of the problem, fix it and add `console.log` statements:

```
onboardingApp.service('apiService', function ($http, $q, $localStorage) {

    //Testing code
    var self = this;

    self.login = (user) => {
        ̶l̶e̶t̶ ̶d̶e̶f̶e̶r̶ ̶=̶ ̶$̶q̶.̶d̶e̶f̶e̶r̶(̶)̶;̶
        let login  = {
            username: user.username,
            password: user.password
        };

        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: `http://ddd.com/login`,
            data: login
        }).then(
            (response) => {
                console.log("success", response);
                setAuthToken(response);
                return response.data;
            },
            (error) => {
               console.log("error",error);
               throw error;
            }
        );
    };    
});
```

This should allow you to diagnose the problem.

---

> After succes login, it should return status code 200 instead of 302. how do I adjust your code to accept 302 as a success instead of an error ?

To **convert** a rejected promise to a successful promise simply `return` values to the rejection handler:

```
       return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: `http://ddd.com/login`,
            data: login
        }).then(
            (response) => {
                console.log("success", response);
                setAuthToken(response);
                return response.data;
            },
            (error) => {
               console.log("error",error);
               if (error.status==302) {
                   console.log("Converting erroneous API response");
                   error.status==200;
                   return error.data;
               };
               //ELSE
               throw error;
            }
        );
```

Comment: Your code show same result as the one I used to have.

Comment: Is it failing without anything logged in the console?

Comment: Status 302 is a "moved permanently" re-direct. The browser should automatically fetch the data from the location specifed. It is not normally passed to the $http service. Is there an [interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors)  configured in the app?

Comment: I even try placing the debugger, it still only go into the error section. https://i.imgur.com/ZymSdMF.png

Comment: It goes into the error section because the status is outside the range 200...299. Status 302 is outside that range. I am baffled as to why the server is responding with a 302 redirect and the browser is not following the redirect. Also the location for the re-direct should be in the header of the response, not in the body of the response.

Comment: You're 100% correct. it's a  of the response code from the backend. After succes login, it should return status code 200 instead of 302. So now.. how do I adjust your code to accept 302 as a success instead of an error ? Just to get this going  while waiting for my BE team fix it.